# Unable to access the properties file in the workspace

Tags: java

I am using the Netbeans IDE for coding, and below is my code to read from a properties file.

```
public class WorkspaceProperties {

public static void main(String [] args) {
     Properties defaultprops = new Properties();
     InputStream  defaultPropFile = null;          
     try {

         defaultPropFile = 
         WorkspaceProperties.class.getClass().getClassLoader().
             getResourceAsStream("config.properties");  
             defaultprops.load(defaultPropFile);
```

The `WorkspaceProperties` class and `config.properties` are in the same package.

But I am not able to read the properties file.

The code throws `NullPointerException` when I am reading it with `getResourceAsStream()` line.

It is a maven-based project in netbeans.

I have tried to give full path of properties file. I have also kept properties in the classes folder but still I cannot read the properties file in my code.

Please help me with this?

Comment: `WorkspaceProperties.class.getClass()` == `Class.class`.

Comment: Use `WorkspaceProperties.class.getResourceAsStream("config.properties")`

Comment: Thank you for the help..